Trying to solve : Intel oneMKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD
I´m trying to implement a Savitsky-Golay filter from the scipy libray .
scipy version is 1.13.1
The error that appears is the one on the title.
The solution recommended I´ve found is to install  the intel-Mkl package from the intel channel .
Would it be correct for an AMD Ryzen 7 CPU ?
Posts about this issue are from a long time ago, so I´m not sure
If yes which of the packages available are necessary ?

MKL still works on AMD, it's just slower.
